# Permalinks is not working in my wordpress setup

Tags: permalinks, mod-rewrite, iis

I am newbie to wordpress.
I have created a site using wordpress and WAMP stack. In my Apache i have enabled **mode_rewrite** , so my site is showing permalinks perfectly.

Now i have hosting provider of .NET and IIS server.
So when i migrated my site to live server it is working fine without permalinks. But when i type using raw url like www.example.com/?p=12 it is working fine. So how can i make it work with IIS just like Apached did..

Is there anything in IIS like **mode_rewrite** in Apache

Comment: Checkout the official manual first: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite

Comment: Have you read and tried Read [Enabling Pretty Permalinks in WordPress on IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rofflox and @toscho for giving me the link.
web.config file was not created as i was working on localhost as WAMP i.e Apache and it required when i shifted to production as it was running IIS.

So i created a blank web.config file and added the following content.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This helped me to accept permalinks perfectly.